Lua not being able to load a script
The following code:
sol::state lua;                                                                      

lua.open_libraries(  sol::lib::base  );

sol::table result = lua.script(   R"( 'machineData={serial=1,name="mob2",}'  )"    );                     

throws the following error:

[sol2] An error occurred and has been passed to an error handler: sol:
syntax error: [string " 'machineData={serial=1,name="mob2",}'  "]:1:
unexpected symbol near ''machineData={serial=1,name="mob2",}''
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'sol::error'


'machineData={serial=1,name="mob2",}' is just invalid lua, what did you expect?

@tkausl: it's a table with two parameters. Isn't it ?

It would be without those ' around it.

@tkausl: thanks, but it still throws:  [sol2] An error occurred and panic has been invoked: stack index 1, expected table, received no value: value is not a table or a userdata that can behave like one (type check failed in constructor)

the solution is simple: your script needs to return the table.You can do so by adding:
return machineData


You should also incoperate the other suggestion regarding the removing the ' around 'machineData={serial=1,name="mob2",}'  in your answer, as right now it does not actually address the issue from the question

@Nifim actually, I still do not get why you need to put the return tableName, when I've done it without it in pure Lua. I mean not using this Lua wrapper (Sol2).
